# Unclear usage of definition of conditional density

Tags: probability

In 'A first course in probability', they define the conditional density function for random variables Y and Z as
$$
  f(y|z) := \frac{f(y, z)}{f_Z(z)}
$$ 
where $f_Z$ is the density of the random variable Z.

But then on page 262 they state that 
$$
  f(x, y | X > 0, Y > 0) = \frac{f(x, y)}{\mathbb{P}(X > 0, Y > 0)}
$$

I don't understand what they mean there. 
How could I reconcile the definition with the statement? 
Or what are they trying to say with $f(x, y | X > 0, Y > 0)$.

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have more context?